# How can I split a text File and use the Integers?

Tags: c#

I have a text file that displays students names and their scores. The format looks like this:

```
James Johnson, 85
Robert Jones, 90
Lindsey Parks, 98
etc.
```

I have 10 names and scores all in the above format. My problem is how do I split the text file by the delimiter, and use the integers from the text file

Here is my code so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
namespace TextFiles1
{
  class Program    
  {        
    static void Main(string[] args)        
    {
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\jonda\Desktop\StudentScores.txt.txt");            
      string data = sr.ReadLine();            
      while (data != null)            
      {                
        Console.WriteLine(data);                
        string[] names = data.Split(',');                
        data = sr.ReadLine();            
      }            
      int total = 0;            
      double average = 0;            
      for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)  
      {   
        total = total + data[index];
      }            
      average = (double)total / data.Length;            
      Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average.ToString("N2"));            
      int high = data[0];            
      for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)                
      {                     
        if (data[index] > high)                     
        {                         
          high = data[index];                     
        }
      }            

      Console.WriteLine("Highest Score =" + high);           
      sr.Close();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Like the previous comment, but instead split on comma instead, the second item in the resulting array you can trycast to an integer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's a good idea to separate file operations and other operations. File operations are slow and costly, and should be completed as soon as possible. I would use a separate method, read the lines into a List and close the file operation first.

```
    private static List<string> ReadFile(string path)
    {
        List<string> records = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                records.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        }
        return records;
    }
```

Then I would pass that list to another function and calculate average, max etc.

```
private static void CalculateAverage(List<string> lines)
{
    char[] seperator = new char[] { ',' };
    List<int> scores = new List<int>();
    if (lines != null && lines.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            string[] parts = line.Split(seperator);
            int val;
            if (int.TryParse(parts[1], out val))
                scores.Add(val);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", scores.Average());
    Console.WriteLine("Highest Score: {0}", scores.Max());
}
```

Then in your main program call the methods like this:

```
List<string> lines = ReadFile(path);
CalculateAverage(lines);
```

Comment: Obviously I haven't done a ton of error handling here, so you should do that as well.

Comment: What do you mean by pass?

Comment: I tries that but it won't accept the return function.

Comment: I don't quite understand you; I compiled and ran the code I provided which worked fine.

Just copy and paste the two methods ReadFile() and CalculateAverage() into the same class where your Main() method is, then inside Main() just copy the last two lines of code I've provided in my answer above. Then it should work.

And please consider marking the above as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: I'm still not getting it to work. When I put in the code it doesn't recognize path in my main function. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to go back to first principals of programming and learn about the basics. Your program doesn't recognize `path` because it's not defined. You need to define a string variable named path, and then assign to it the actual path of the file you're reading, in your case, `string path = @"C:\Users\jonda\Desktop\StudentScores.txt.txt");`

Please do try to understand the basics of programming first.

Comment: Also a good habit is to try to investigate what's wrong. When you compile your program, the above code gives you an error message, and if you tried reading it, you could most of the time either figure out the problem or at the very least get an idea about what to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to find each person info and then split each of them and extract `Name` and `Score`.

Try like this:

```
        var inputStr = "James Johnson, 85 Robert Jones, 90 Lindsey Parks, 98";
        var regex = new Regex(@"[A-z]* [A-z]*, [0-9]*");
        return  regex.Matches(inputStr)
            .OfType<Match>()
           .Select(p => p.Value.Split(','))
           .Select(p => new { Name = p[0], Score = Convert.ToInt32(p[1].Trim()) });
```

Result : 
[image: The result]

I hope to be helpful for you :)